# good kids related magento templates

Tags: theme, template

we are developing kids related toys, cloths magento site

So planning to buy some very good templates.  which templates

development company will give good support for customization.

please help us to find some good templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have suggest below templates. so have got some more ideas.

**1.** On [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/themes/toys-baby-products.html)

**2.** On theme Forest [Kid Store Magento Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/kid-store-magento-theme/2064956)

**3.** On Theme Forest [Kids Store - Magento Responsive Template](http://themeforest.net/item/kids-store-magento-responsive-template/6669273)

**4.** On Template monster [Magento Baby Themes](http://www.templatemonster.com/category/baby-store-magento-themes/)

Please look into this themes.